# WPF Disable Highlighting on ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I am failing to achieve a simple task in WPF.
I want to keep the "normal" color of the selected item in a ListView, instead of making it blue. I try to do this using the style triggers, but they somehow don't seem to work.

I can't even make them red.

```
    <ListView x:Name="orderListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableOrders}" Margin="0,54,0,0" SelectionMode="Single" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedOrder}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OrderListTemplate}" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey color.

```
 <ListView.Style>
            <Style >
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />                        
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>
```